# window is not defined angular universal third library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am working with the library ng2-mqtt and I used it im my component like this:

```
 import 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js';
declare var Paho: any;
```

Now I am getting following error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em3/node_modules/ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js:2143:4)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Picchu/Documents/em3/dist/server.js:18707:18)
> ```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can run this part of the code selectively only in the browser by using isPlatformBrowser available in angular/common

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way to avoid server error is not to render the component(if it is an option) that uses `window`. Something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isBrowser">
   <!-- mqttws31-component -->
   <mqttws31-component></mqttws31-component> 
</ng-container>
```

The isBrowser can be imported from(**ng2**)

```
import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal';
```

Or if **ng4+**, you can also define this in your browser module:

```
// app.browser
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'isBrowser', useValue: true }
  ]
})
```

then inject from constructor

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject('isBrowser') private isBrowser: boolean)
  ngOnInit() { 
    // example usage, this could be anywhere in this Component of course
    if (this.isBrowser) { 
      alert('we're in the browser!');
    }
}
```

Comment: With latest Angular version, we can use angular provided injectors instead of manually providing **useValues**. Provided my solution below.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

Extending Leon Li's answer, we can avoid loading components that cannot be rendered on server side if it requires Browser APIs like location or window.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761386/1161370) explains how to use

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
  this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}
```

Just inject PLATFORM_ID into your service, and pass it to `isPlatformBrowser` or `isPlatformServer`to get a Boolean value. Accordingly you can show/hide the components that cannot be rendered on server if they depend on Browser APIs.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 6 In server.ts use:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync('dist/browser/index.html').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
```

Comment: will this works on angular universal ssr ?

Comment: Just tried on Angular Universal SSR, but now I'm getter a new error `ReferenceError: SVG is not defined`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Tried in angular 14.

Answer (score 3):

`window` shouldn't be used in universal applications on server side, because Node.js doesn't have `window`, and having a dummy `global.window` currently affects the way Angular detects global variable.

If the package uses `window`, an issue can be opened in its repository and/or it can be forked and changed to not use `window`.

Since packages that rely on `window` often rely on things that are specific to client side, they won't work as expected on server side even if this issue is sorted out.

[Package description](https://github.com/icanos/ng2-mqtt) says:

> Depends on the library from: https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/

While [library description](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) says:

> The Paho JavaScript Client is an MQTT **browser-based client library** written in Javascript that uses WebSockets to connect to an MQTT Broker.

Usually third-party Angular module that isn't supposed to work as expected on server side should be stubbed or mocked; dummy module with fake directives and services is imported in `app.server.ts` instead of real module.

Comment: Ok, I didn't really understand. Is there a way to solve this problem? Should I create a globa variable window within my node.js app and how and where should I do this?

Comment: See the last paragraph. It's applicable to your case. It totally depends on how the module is used in your app, i.e. how this module affects the page that is generated on server side. Also, consider opening an issue. It's vendor's responsibility to provide a module that won't cause an error in universal app.

Comment: I already opened the issue in the repo. I am using the module as client but the error is occuring on server side. I am not sure how I can solve this. However thanx for your help

Comment: Do not import `ng2-mqtt` module in server app. If its import results in `Paho` global variable (I guess it is), create dummy `global.Paho` variable in server app that stubs or mocks the behaviour that is expected from this module. And actually, I don't see anything that is specific to Angular in this module, even though it has `ng2` prefix. It's just a library that exposes a global (that's why globals are bad).

Comment: The point is that `Paho` global **shouldn't** work, because real ng2-mqtt **shouldn't** be imported on server side. Instead, `Paho` global should be replaced with dummy implementation of the module. Because real ng2-mqtt won't work in Node.js.

Comment: Ok, I understood that I should not import ng2-mqtt on server side. After compiling it is automatically required in my server.js. How can I avoid this? With webpack?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible. The package is included in the app only if it's imported. You should have `import 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js'` in client-side bundle but don't have it in server-side bundle. And yes, you can also address this with webpack and substitute `ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js` module with something else with [alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) feature.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me **ng9+**

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'isBrowser', useValue: true }
  ]
})
```

and replace absolute path (remove first **/**):

/assets/images/... to assets/images/...