# ReferenceError: window is not defined in angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, angular-seo

I am trying to use `@nguniversal/express-engine` and I have installed and trying to run it but its giving error in main.js file.

This is the error I am getting

```
    C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:179450
})(window, function() {
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.rdXg (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:179450:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.+PDj (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:133:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.xCqK (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:198481:92)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.xLoe (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:200042:86)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.Mm/0 (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:89135:105)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Folder\ssr\dist\ssr\server\main.js:26:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:59195
```

I have tried many thing but nothing working.

print function causing the issue and the print function is been used by print-js library

```
 const contentToConvert = document.getElementById('content');
this.selectedFunctionCode = htmlToImage.toPng;
const debugBase64 = this.debugBase64;
this.selectedFunctionCode(contentToConvert)
  .then((dataUrl) => {
        print(dataUrl, 'image');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
```

Comment: chech this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922178/angular-7-universal-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined

Comment: thats not it in above suggestion the error is coming in server.js file but in my case its in main.js

Answer (score 1):

because some object like localstorage, window use in client side are not defined in server side you must first check your browser platform is ready then work with these objectes
for this you can do like:

at first generate check-is-browserService.service.ts like this:

```
export class CheckIsBrowserService {
  private isBrowser = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

  constructor() {}

  getIsBrowser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.isBrowser;
  }

  setIsBrowser(value: any) {
    this.isBrowser.next(value);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any, 
  private checkIsBrowserService: CheckIsBrowserService
){
  this.checkIsBrowserService.setIsBrowser(isPlatformBrowser(platformId));
}
```

then generate service for example window.service.ts

```
class Window implements Window {
  readonly innerWidth: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WindowService {
  private config: Window;

  constructor(private checkIsBrowserService: CheckIsBrowserService) {
    this.config = new Window();
    this.checkIsBrowserService.getIsBrowser().subscribe((isBrowser) => {
      if (isBrowser) {
        this.config = window;
      }
    });
  }
  innerWidth() {
    return this.config.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

and when in your component use window.innerwidth you must change it to

x.component.ts:

```
 constructor(private window: WindowService) {
   if (this.window.innerWidth() <= 1024) {
     //your code
   }
 }
```

Comment: still getting the same error after doing all changes. would @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) this also be need to be in condition

Comment: are you sure do all changes ? because i test it know and work fine with  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']). no this condition is only for test if you want use window.innerWidth and at the end if is ok for you can you share your code

Comment: yes there is print() function which is giving error