# Getting 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' when tried to run Angular App with Server-Side Rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I use Angular for my application.
I'm able to build for web and ssr but i have this error when i run : npm run serve:ssr:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I have added this code in my server.ts

```
const mocks = require('mock-browser').delegates.AbstractBrowser;
const MockBrowser = mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
(global as any).document = mock.getDocument();
(global as any).navigator = mock.getNavigator();
(global as any).window = mock.getWindow();
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

StackTrace :

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at 18214 (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:5590934)
> at **webpack_require** (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:6617720)
> at 12643 (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:5563790)
> at **webpack_require** (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:6617720)
> at 20783 (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:3091635)
> at **webpack_require** (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:6617720)
> at 30097 (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:694)
> at **webpack_require** (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:6617720)
> at 96846 (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:39497)
> at **webpack_require** (/home/nico/Private/tchat.cafe/front/dist/front/server/main.js:1:6617720)

I never use window object in my components.

Does someone can help me ?

Comment: Do you have any imports before this code ? Can you determine in the stacktrace which package is accessing `window` ?

Comment: I think this answers will help you, 
1. https://medium.com/motf-creations/angular-universal-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-f0ed140e3210
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282920/referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-ssr-angular

Comment: no the stackstrace don't give this information. I added it in post

Comment: Just add a [`isPlatformServer`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/sticky-footer/src/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.component.ts#L12) check to `*ngIf` hide the offending component

Answer (score 1):

you will get the error because you are using window and other global objects, in the server mode so when Angular compiles the app it sees the expression

```
(global as any).window = mock.getWindow();
```

And throws the error.

Solution:
not sure why you need it but angular provides access global objects with dependency injection, and when it's server mode it safely mocks them

Example:

access Document

```
   @import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common"
    
   //Some component
   constructor(private @Inject(DOCUMENT) document:Document){
   }
```

access Window

```
  @import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common"
    
   //Some component
   constructor(private @Inject(DOCUMENT) document:Document){
           document.defaultView //defaultView is the window object
   }
```

by accessing those object you can reach to everything else

Comment: I don't understand where i need to put this code. I never use window in my components.

Comment: i remove code above from my server.ts and i still get the error

Comment: when you get the error, you should also get the stacktrace where you get it, could you paste the code of this stacktrace ? or  you can find in the project anywhere you use window. ( with search functionality ) and paste it here so I can check

Comment: i never use window in src directory and i past the stack trace in the question. I don't have other information