# Angular 12 Universal Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace

Tags: node.js, angular, express, universal

I created new project - client - on Angular 11.
Then updated ng version to 12 Angular.
Then installed Universal:
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

Then I'm trying to run my Universal Angular, but it throws error:

npm run dev:ssr

> client@0.0.0 dev:ssr
> ng run client:serve-ssr

---

This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!

---

Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\PRACTICE\MYPETPROJECTS\tanechka\client
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c ng run client:serve-ssr

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-08T14_35_07_681Z-debug.log

angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractLicenses": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "client:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "client:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "client:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "client:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run client:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/client/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run client:server",
    "prerender": "ng run client:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.0.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^12.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

I tried to add 'development' to 'configurations' of serve:

```js
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I came across this problem today. Just make sure architect.serve,  architect.server, architect.serve, architect.serve-ssr and architect.prerender all have configuration for development, staging and production steps.

Answer (score 32):

**FIXED Angular 12 Universal running `serve:ssr` but showing `Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace`**

My angular project was updated from 11 to 12.

I need to add angular universal for some reason and got same issue.

Trying to add `development` in `architect.configurations` where contents copied from production, but not working.

Finally, I removed `:development` in `serve-ssr.configurations.development` and it works well.

In `angular.json` snippet

```json
"serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>:build", <--- remove `:development` here
              "serverTarget": "<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>:server"  <--- remove `:development` here
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>:production",
              "serverTarget": "<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks it was a great help.  It would be great if question also mentioned `serve:ssr` in title so its easy to catch.

Comment: OK. adding a bold text at first line about this issue.

Comment: Thanks man , It Works !

Comment: there is a big issue now like this:ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: @withoutOne Try to follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922178/angular-7-universal-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined/61533047#61533047

Answer (score 5):

here the answer
In angular, you can create your own workspace like development, production in **angular.json** file.
follow this:-

1. go to angular.json file in the app root folder
2. under the projects >"YOUR_APP_NAME" >architect >serve-ssr >configurations add this

```
"development": {
      "browserTarget": "YOUR_APP_NAME:build:development",
      "serverTarget": "YOUR_APP_NAME:server:development"
            }
```

**node:** if alredy added
3. go to architect >**server** >configurations add this

```
"development": {
      "optimization": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractLicenses": true
      }
```

4. go to architect >serve >configurations add this

```
"development": {
       "browserTarget": "YOUR_APP_NAME:build:development"
        }
```

5. if you build app go to architect >build >configurations add this

```
"development":{
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
```

6. go to architect >prerender >configurations add this

```
"development": {
              "browserTarget": "YOUR_APP_NAME:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "YOUR_APP_NAME:server:development"
            }
```

this configuration work for me
then you can run `# npm run serve:ssr`

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same issue, my first go at Universal.

I added a "development" configuration in the follow nodes in the angular.json: -

```
projects->{project-name}->architect->build->configurations
projects->{project-name}->architect->server->configurations
```

As I normally run with "production" and "staging" configurations I just copied the staging configuration and made a couple of tweaks to stop file replacements and give me an easy platform to debug on while I got used to server side rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I created issue on this topic on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2158

The working decision is:
Could you try to delete this line on serve-ssr: "defaultConfiguration": "development" and "configuration.development path. Then add options below builder like this:
"options": { "browserTarget": "client:build", "serverTarget": "client:server" },

Angular.json must have such view (with Universal)

```js
 "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular12-universal:build",
            "serverTarget": "angular12-universal:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular12-universal:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "angular12-universal:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

Change angular12-universal on name of your project

```js
 "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-project-name-here:build",
            "serverTarget": "your-project-name-here:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "your-project-name-here:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "your-project-name-here:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

2. Note, in version 12, there is also a new experimental way of SSR, To opt-in you can use ng add @nguniversal/common.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing helps. So I delete the project with Angular 12 and create a new one with Angular 11 and add Universal, run dev:ssr and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `development` configuration in `angular.json`. You can use multiple configurations in that file to separate builds for development, staging and production.

Create a copy of `architect.build.configurations.production` named `development` or however you wish (I used `dev` for this example, to show you how it works). For example:

```
{
  "projects": {
...
      "architect": {
...
          "configurations": {
...
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
...
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

In the `serve-ssr` section you can now refer to the configurations you want. Please note the change I made where I replaced `development` with `dev`, to demystify what's going on.

```
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "labeler:build:dev",
              "serverTarget": "labeler:server:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "labeler:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "labeler:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "dev"
        },
```

Running `npm run dev:ssr` should now work.

To read more about the ability to add multiple configurations to your project, go here: https://angular.io/guide/build