# Angular Universal sessionStorage is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have moved my application from Angular 6 to Angular Universal and since doing this I have noticed this error in the console:

> sessionStorage is not defined

It is moaning about this service:

```
export class SessionService {
  constructor(
    private key: string
  ) { 
  }

  save(json: any) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(json));
  }

  get() {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.key));
  }

  clear() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

I have seen that you can do something like:

```
 if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return;
```

but this service is actually extended like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { SessionService } from './session.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionSessionService extends SessionService {
  constructor() {
    super(
      'questions'
    );
  }
}
```

So I can't add `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object` to the constructor.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812124/angular-isplatformbrowser-checking-against-platform-id-doesnt-prevent-server-si

Comment: did you try to inject `PLATFORM_ID` in the parent service?

Comment: I don't think I can do that, because it would make all other services (that extend it) require an extra constructor parameter

Answer (score 0):

inside your sessionService add check whether you are on the browser side or not by

```
if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId));
```

if you are on the browser-side do what you are now doing. but if you are on the SR side use memoryStorage or any other non operable dummy registration which would not cause this error.

hope it helps.

Comment: I can't do that, I have already stated that because the service is injected I can't add anything to the constructor because it messes with all the services that extend the base class......

Comment: can't you consider altering sessionStorage on any other layer only for SR? so it wont be null on SR side?